# Formik form template for xml document creation

Tags: xml, reactjs, forms, xml-parsing, formik

I am building a react form with Formik library. My aim is to create an xml document with the form's input. My approach is that if I could create a nicely structured JS Object with Formik, then I could write a function to write these form fields into an xml scheme.

Now I know that with Formik's `<FieldArray />` [component](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/fieldarray), I can create nested objects and this could help me to handle parent and child elements of the xml file creation later but I really need help about how can I deal with the xml attributes inside the object. Attributes are also part of the form. User should be able to enter them as normal form fields. I am desperately looking for a solution. Below I presented a scheme for the desired xml document and my desired form field. 
[image]

```
  <creators>
   <creator>
     <creatorName nameType="Personal">Miller, Elizabeth</creatorName>
     <givenName>Elizabeth</givenName>
     <familyName>Miller</familyName>
     <nameIdentifier schemeURI="organi.org/" nameIdentifierScheme="ORC">7</nameIdentifier>
     <affiliation>DataCite</affiliation>
   </creator>
  </creators>
```

Could someone give me an example how to create a `<FieldArray />` component that could be useful to create above schemed xml document?

Update: 
Thank you so much @rutherford-wonkington for your answer.

I see you try to solve my problem of attributes by adding 'value' key to the JS object. That was exactly what I was looking for. According to your suggestion, with a little modification, I created a component below. Do you think this component will close the deal? Then I could re-edit this post and accept your answer.

```
import { FieldArray, Form, Field,Formik } from "formik";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";




export const Creators = () => (
    <div>
        <h1>Creators</h1>
        <Formik
            initialValues={{
                creator: [
            {creatorName: {value: "Elisabeth, Miller", nameType: "Personal"}}, {givenName: 'Elisabeth'},
            {familyName: "Miller"},
            {nameIdentifier: {value:'7', schemeURI: "organi.org/", nameIdentifierScheme:"ORC"}},
            {affiliation: "Cook"}
            ]}}
            render={({ values }) => (
                <Form>
                    <FieldArray
                        name="creator"
                        render={arrayHelpers => (
                            <div>
                                {values.creator.map((creator, index) => (
                                    <div>
                                        <Field name={`creator.${index}.creatorName.value`} />
                                        <Field name={`creator.${index}.creatorName.nameType`} />
                                        <Field name={`creator.${index}.givenName`} />
                                        <Field name={`creator.${index}.familyName`} />
                                        <Field name={`creator.${index}.nameIdentifier.value`} />
                                        <Field name={`creator.${index}.nameIdentifier.schemeURI`} />
                                        <Field name={`creator.${index}.nameIdentifier.nameIdentifierScheme`} />
                                        <Field name={`creator.${index}.affiliation`} />

                                        <Button type="button" onClick={() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)}>
                                            -
                                        </Button>
                                    </div>
                                ))}
                                <Button color="primary"
                                        type="button"
                                        onClick={() => arrayHelpers.push({})}
                                >
                                    Add New
                                </Button>
                            </div>
                        )}
                    />
                    <pre>{JSON.stringify(values, null,2 )}</pre>
                </Form>
            )}
        />
    </div>
);
```

Comment: I'd recommend turning your fields themselves into objects, you could then use the Formik object functionality to relate each attribute to the appropriate input in your form. It's hard to be more specific without seeing how your form and data are set up.

Comment: Also, how are you parsing this data?  FieldArray is generally used for arrays, but I think it would make more sense here to just use nested objects and give each field it's own singular value. You can still have all the values on the same "level" on the object. Unless you mean to have multiple creators in one form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can structure your data like so:

```js
const initialValues = {
  creators: [
    {
      creatorName: {
        value: "Miller, Elizabeth",
        nameType: "Personal"
      },
      givenName: "Elizabeth",
      familyName: "Miller",
      nameIdentifier: {
        value: "7",
        schemeURI: "organi.org/",
        nameIdentifierScheme: "ORC"
      },
      affiliation: "DataCite"
    }
  ]
};
```

It shouldn't be too hard to see how you can relate each value and option to its own specific value using dot notation in the name field.  You can use `FieldArray` to map over the creators array and generate a set of `Fields` for each value and option, like in this example from the Formik docs:

```
<Form>
  <FieldArray
    name="friends"
    render={arrayHelpers => (
      <div>
        {values.friends.map((friend, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <Field name={`friends[${index}].name`} />
            <Field name={`friends.${index}.age`} /> {/* both these conventions do the same */}
            <button type="button" onClick={() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)}>
              -
            </button>
          </div>
        ))}
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => arrayHelpers.push({ name: '', age: '' })}
        >
          +
        </button>
      </div>
    )}
  />
</Form>
```

When you're parsing your object into XML, just use `value` for the value, and apply the other fields as properties.

Comment: I see, you solve the problem of the attributes of the xml doc with the 'value'  key in the object. But then I thought I should add value key to every tag in order to be consistent for writing my xml converter function later. Am I right? I provided the component code inside the question, thank you for help again.

Comment: That wouldn't be necessary.  You can just check if an object has keys and have your parser behave accordingly. Happy to help!